# Video link not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: videos

I uploaded video through media and linked that video in one of our page. The video is working fine on Chrome and Mozilla Firefox broswer but not working on IE.
Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: please share link or code snippet

Comment: Some file types don't automatically work in all browsers. What type of video did you upload?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply both of you. I am using mp4 format.

Comment: <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/dmeo.mp4" target="_blank">Demo</a>

Comment: @Swati what is the exactly issue, link is not working or video is not playing?

Comment: Video link is not working. When I click on video link it showing page with this value"A_HžO S63w$9o§?3%CÓÜÿæs Û s ‹ ä= …'q4+ =* ? c7 Ûé6ê‰ ³ Æ ˜  Í´d.Øá-y2¸}¡(((&|à*ÿ"é¼""=D Èß "î%@t%ô¼%÷"

Comment: can you share link?

Comment: Sorry. Its on Internal network not the public website. :(

Comment: I'm still confused. Do you want to play the video or download when demo is clicked? Because above code indicates that video will start downloading...

Comment: I am ok with both the options. Like it would be great if video will play on new tab when i click on video link or it could download. but nothing is happening. Showing error data when i click on Video link on IE

Comment: what happens in Chrome?

Comment: Video play on new tab. No issue with Chrome and Mozilla FireFox

Comment: What is the resolution of video and what is IE version?

Comment: Video Resolution: 1440x1090 and IE Version: 11